# clang -module-file-info doesn't generate any output

Tags: clang, llvm-clang

I'm trying to move a cross-compiled CMake project to Clang Modules to see whether compile time reduction is worth it. However, it seems that Clang is generating lots of duplicate modules in it's ModuleCache.

I'd like to figure out why (maybe some CMake config, etc), so I'm trying to run `clang -module-file-info` on the generated module files.

However, clang's output is just empty whenever I provide a proper module file. Am I doing anything wrong? Is there anything special that I need to take care of?

The files all have a reasonable size (from a few kB to a few MB), look fine in a Hex editor (start with CPCH, have some recognizable strings, etc) and whenever I specify a wrong file (or a file compiled with a different version of clang) I get the appropriate errors.
I've tried with clang 7.0.1 as well as 8.0.0.

I also tried `--verbose` but that didn't show any problems either.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question:

clang doesn't output the stats on the command line, it puts it into a file by default written in the current directory.